# Exception trying to use a basic Expression created with LinqKit

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0, linqkit, ef-core-2.1

I'm trying to force ef-core to paramerize values that it considers constants as described in [this article](http://devmate.net/2017/10/entity-framework-the-query-plan-cache-story/) by using LinqKit.

When trying to apply the PredicateBuilder example described [on github](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), I get an exception. This is my code:

```
    private async Task getWallets()
    {
        var query =
            from w in _context.Wallets.AsExpandable()
            where w.WalletItems.Any(hasItems().Compile())
            select w;

        var result = await query.ToListAsync();
    }

    private Expression<Func<WalletItem, bool>> hasItems()
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<WalletItem>();
        var ids = new string[] { "A", "B" };

        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            predicate = predicate.Or(wi => wi.ExternalId == id);
        }
        return predicate;            
    }
```

When hitting ToListAsync() the following exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Could not parse expression 'w.WalletItems.Any(__Compile_0)': The given arguments did not match the expected arguments: Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.'

I am running the code in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application (netcoreapp2.1) using the following packages:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational (2.1.1)
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (2.1.1)
- LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (1.1.15)

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing in the examples is the fact that all `Expression<Func<..>>` are either parameters or local variables. While the line

```
where w.WalletItems.Any(hasItems().Compile())
```

is not actually calling the `hasItems` method, but emits a [`MethodCallExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression(v=vs.110).aspx) (i.e. [`Expression.Call`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.call(v=vs.110).aspx)) to it inside the query expression tree, which is different type of expression not recognized by LINQKit `Expand` implementation, thus leading to unsupported expression by EF Core.

The solution is to put the method call result into a local variable and use that variable inside the query expression tree:

```
var hasItemsExpr = hasItems();

var query =
    from w in _context.Wallets.AsExpandable()
    where w.WalletItems.Any(hasItemsExpr.Compile())
    select w;
```